# Npgsql - running a user specified query as readonly

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

Given that the user specified in the connection string has write/alter/etc. permissions, is there a reliable way to prevent data modification when running a user provided query (as specified by 'query' in the variable query below)?

```
using (NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (NpgsqlCommand setReadonlyCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;", conn, transaction))
    {
        setReadonlyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn, transaction))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //... read query results
        }
    }

    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

The snippet above has two safety nets - running in the readonly transaction, and rolling back transaction at the end.

But both of these can be overridden easily by the user by adding statements "SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;" and "COMMIT;"

Is there a more sophisticated way of ensuring ad-hoc queries don't make any changes to the database?

Please note that we do not have access to the DB itself, so cannot create any SPs, roles, etc. to help solve this issue. All we have in this case is user specified connection string and user query.

Comment: Create a user who only have a role to select so they have no permissions to start transactions or anything like that. Just saw the last bit of your question. Get access to your database.

Comment: Would it be better to build out abstraction in the form of an abstraction layer such as Entity Framework? Why is there a requirement for a user to enter a SQL Query directly?